# How To "Unaccess" A File So Other Parts Of The Program Can Access It

Tags: c#, runtime-error, file-access

I had the following code dispersed throughout my program.  However I always seem to get the error below.  Even though I am using a "using bracket" to dispose of resources I still don't know why this is happening.

Error:

> The Process cannot access the file "the file path" because it is being used by another process.

Code:

```
string folderpath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "AGoogleHistory");
string filecreate;


private void restoreTbasToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filecreate))
    {
        string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
        MessageBox.Show(s, "History", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}

try
{
    browser.Navigate(new Uri(Address));
    using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filecreate))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(Address);
    }
}
catch(System.UriFormatException)
{
    return;
}


private void clearToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        File.Delete(filecreate);
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Your image was a link to the imgur homepage. I removed it. Please don't post images of errors anyway, just text, please.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first check that file is exists or not by

```
File.Exists(filePath);
```

Second thing you are passing wrong parameter to `StreamReader` class which is an empty string as you haven't assigned anything to it. Check above mentioned things first and you can refer below link for your ease :

[The process cannot access file...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27959950/the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process)

Let me know if you have any other issue after trying this.

Answer (score 0):

StreamReader, by default, locks the file.  This causes the error you are seeing.  Luckily, StreamReader accepts a stream as one of it's overloads for it's constructor. This allows you to first create a FileStream, which has a handy enum allowing you to specify read/write sharing, then pass that FileStream to your StreamReader for use.

So in your case:

```
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filecreate))
...
```

becomes:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filecreate, FileMode.Open, FileShare.ReadWrite);
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
...
```

For more info, see the question below.  It's essentially the same question, just asked differently.  The accepted answer should explain a bit more.

[How to open a StreamReader in ShareDenyWrite mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478512/how-to-open-a-streamreader-in-sharedenywrite-mode)

**EDIT**

Looking over your question again, I see that part of your problem is you don't close your streams.  They *should* get closed when the using block exits, but it's best practice to close them yourself with `sr.Close();`

Also, you may need to add the delete flag to the fileshare option:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filecreate, FileMode.Open, FileShare.ReadWrite|FileShare.Delete);
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
...
```